# ElasticSearch aggregation return name and count of key

Tags: elasticsearch

With the following json

```
{
  "doc1": {
    "interests": {
      "community-engagement": 55,
      "martech-developer": 7,
      "digital-marketing": 10
     }
  },
  "doc2": {
    "interests": {
      "community-engagement": 23,
      "martech-developer": 7,
      "content-marketing": 10
     }
  }
}
```

Note that source was stored in Tracardi profile index so it might be a little bit different to this source sample.

When I tried to do this ...

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "interests",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then a count of the values of the interests is returned ...

```
{
  "55":1,
  "23":1,
  "7":2,
  "10":2
}
```

Have removed all the buckets, etc from results for brevity.

I feel like some sort of nesting is required, but am unsure about how to go about it.

How do I get the following result that shows a count of the interests.key and not a count of the value, for example ...

```
{
  "community-engagement":2,
  "martech-developer":2,
  "digital-marketing":1,
  "content-marketing":1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue following is the solution.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_interests": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "def result = []; def interests = params['_source']['interests']; for (entry in interests.entrySet()) { result.add(entry.getKey()); } return result;",
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```